# Как с помощью retrofit 2 парсить массивы в массивах

Tags: java, android, json, retrofit

У меня есть три сущности: `Category, subcategory, item`.
Сервер выдает JSON такого вида: Массив Category, внутри него массив subcategory, внутри него массив item. Это всё выдается одним `JSON`'ом.

**Вопрос:** Как мне их правильно спарсить и положить в arraylist? Ложить нужно будет в 3 array list, или же в один array list? Я не очень это понимаю. Я умею парсить один массив с одной сущностью, но проблемы возникают когда нужно спарсить массив массивов.
Буду рад ссылкам на туториалы, как это делается с помощью retrofit 2 или похожей либой.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По своему опыту посоветую использовать вот этот сайт: http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

Просто возьмите ваш JSON полностью, скопируйте его туда, выберите `Source type: JSON`, `Annotation style: GSON`, укажите ваш пекейдж и желаемое имя класса для самого верхнего в иерархии класса, затем нажмите превью (либо скачайте архивом), немного подредактируйте, если нужно, и всё.

Затем, как обычно, `.enqueue(new Callback<MyResponse>())`, где `MyResponse` - "верхний в иерархии класс", про который я написал чуть выше.

Затем внутри метода `public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<MyResponse> call, @NonNull Response<MyResponse> response) {` у вас будет response - десериализованный объект вашего ответа от сервера. Если бы вы привели пример жсона, было бы проще показать пример.

---

Увидел ваш пример JSON, проделал тоже самое, что и описал выше.

Не очень хорошо, правда, что у вас корневой элемент в ответе от сервера это массив, лучше сделайте что-то вроде `{"response":[]}`, а в `response` запишите тот массив, который возвращается сейчас, так будет проще.

Если учесть эту ремарку, тогда просто скачайте архив, который вам даст сайт, поместите его себе в проект (если, конечно, пекейджи и прочее указаны правильно) и затем работайте с ретрофитом.

Будет что-то такое:

```
myApi.callSomeMethod(param).enqueue(new Callback<MyResponse>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<MyResponse> call, @NonNull Response<MyResponse> response) {
        MyResponse myresponse = response.body();
        List<com.package.Response> responseList = myresponse.getResponse();
        Category category = responseObject.get(0).getCategory();
        // и так далее
        // я мог ошибиться в каких-то мелочах, но суть примерно такая
    }
```

Comment: вот пример моего JSON'a - http://139.59.164.239:8080/tubeserver/menu

Comment: @ВиталийБелоусов дополнил ответ.

Comment: спасибо! не совсем понятен ваш ответ, но попробую на свежую голову разобраться. Может быть есть какие-то туториалы на счет этой темы? Статьи какие-нибудь чтобы почитать и понять как это все работает?

Comment: @ВиталийБелоусов Вот очень крутая статья: https://habrahabr.ru/post/314028/ - и, если ответ помогает решить проблему вопроса, поставьте галочку, она чуть левее самого ответа :)

Comment: всё получилось, спасибо большое!